# IF ERRORLEVEL with net user command

Tags: batch-file, cmd, errorlevel

I need help with some batch. I created this batch file using conditional processing statements to detect errors. For this batch file, NO conditional processing characters should remain. I need to remove those and use "IF ERRORLEVEL" to detect errors. We cannot use "IF %ERRORLEVEL%" or anything advanced, we are just in an introductory phase. We need to use the net user command as well. I am stuck.

*Original Code that Works with Conditional Processing Statements:*

```
@echo off

rem Check if the account already exists before creating account. If it does not exist, go to :FAIL
net user | find /i "%1" >nul 2>&1 && GOTO FAIL 

rem Add a user if the account does not exist and then go to :SUCCESS
net user %1 %1 /add >nul 2>&1 || GOTO ERROR
GOTO SUCCESS

rem If the user does not already exist and is succesfully added
:SUCCESS
echo The %1 user was succesfully added.
GOTO :EOF

rem If the user already exists
:FAIL
echo The %1 user already exists on this computer.
echo Please use a different username.
GOTO :EOF

rem Send system generated errors messages to ECHO
:ERROR
echo An Error was generated when attempting to create the user
echo    These are the things you can check:
echo        Did you open the command prompt as administrator?
echo        If passwords are required on your system, did you include one?
GOTO :EOF

:END
```

What I know:

- If the account already exists the errorlevel is 0.
- If the account does not exist and it is created, the errorlevel is 0.
- If the command prompt is not run as an admin or password policy not
  met, the errorlevel is 2.

**Actually I don't know any of that stuff because it seems like my errorlevel is changing the more I experiment... I'm stuck... One of the command prompts I was getting errorlevel 1 so... also is GOTO :EOF conditional processing?**

How do I accomplish this script? I am stuck. Tried some things but ultimately stuck. Here's what I have that I gave up on.

*Code I have with no conditional processing statements and IF ERRORLEVEL:*

```
@echo off

IF ERRORLEVEL 2 (
    rem Send system generated errors messages to ECHO

    echo An Error was generated when attempting to create the user
    echo    These are the things you can check:
    echo        Did you open the command prompt as administrator?
    echo        If passwords are required on your system, did you include one?
    GOTO :EOF
)

:: Check if the account already exists before creating account. If it does not exist, go to :FAIL
net user | find /i "%1"

    IF ERRORLEVEL 0 (
        rem If the user already exists
        echo The %1 user already exists on this computer.
        echo Please use a different username.
        GOTO :EOF
        )

:: Add a user if the account does not exist and then go to :SUCCESS
net user %1 %1 /add

        IF ERRORLEVEL 0 (
            REM If the user does not already exist and is succesfully added
            echo The %1 user was succesfully added.
            GOTO :EOF
            )


:END
```

Comment: Note: `if errorlevel <n>` is actually processed as "if errorlevel is <n> or higher", so `if errorlevel 0` does acutally just check, if errorlevel is not negative. You probably want `if not errorlevel 1`

Answer (score 0):

The only time an error would be generated when creating a user would be right after trying to create a user, so that error check needs to move to that part of the code. However, since `if ERRORLEVEL 0` means "if ERRORLEVEL is 0 or higher" and 2 is higher than 0, you need to move the `IF ERRORLEVEL 2` code block between the `net user add` and last `IF ERRORLEVEL 0` lines. Also, you *want* the `net user` to fail, so we need to redirect script flow before `if errorlevel 0` gets picked up.

```
@echo off

:: Check if the account already exists before creating account.
net user "%~1"

IF ERRORLEVEL 2 GOTO ADD_USER
IF ERRORLEVEL 0 (
    rem If the user already exists
    echo The %1 user already exists on this computer.
    echo Please use a different username.
    GOTO :EOF
)

:: Add a user if the account does not exist and then go to :SUCCESS
:ADD_USER
net user %1 %1 /add

IF ERRORLEVEL 2 (
    rem Send system generated errors messages to ECHO

    echo An Error was generated when attempting to create the user
    echo    These are the things you can check:
    echo        Did you open the command prompt as administrator?
    echo        If passwords are required on your system, did you include one?
    GOTO :EOF
)

IF ERRORLEVEL 0 (
    REM If the user does not already exist and is succesfully added
    echo The %1 user was succesfully added.
    GOTO :EOF
)

:END
```

The wording of your homework only mentions conditional processing **symbols**, not all conditional processing in general, so that just means you can't use `||` or `&&`.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to create a user using `net.exe`'s `user` command, and then try to handle any issues from doing so, afterwards; I would offer the following approach using the built-in WMI command line utility [wmic](/questions/tagged/wmic). The idea is to check your input username against a list of all existing standard local users, *(which aren't built-in/special)*, and only proceed if a duplicate username doesn't already exist.

```bat
@If "%~1"=="" (Echo No username provided as an input argument.
    "%__AppDir__%timeout.exe" 3 /NoBreak>NUL&GoTo :EOF)
@SetLocal DisableDelayedExpansion
@Set "Usr=%~1"
@Call :UsrsLst "%Usr%"
@If ErrorLevel 2 (Echo The username already exists.
    "%__AppDir__%timeout.exe" 3 /NoBreak>NUL&GoTo :EOF
)Else If ErrorLevel 1 Echo You have no existing standard local users.
@If ErrorLevel 0 Echo Creating user %Usr% . . .
@"%__AppDir__%timeout.exe" 3 /NoBreak>NUL
@EndLocal&GoTo :EOF

:UsrsLst
@For /F "Delims==" %%G In ('Set Usrs 2^>NUL')Do @Set "%%G="
@For /F Tokens^=2Delims^=^" %%G In ('^""%__AppDir__%wbem\WMIC.exe"^
     Path Win32_UserProfile Where "Special!='True' And LocalPath Is Not Null"^
     Assoc:List 2^>NUL^"')Do @For /F Tokens^=4Delims^=^" %%H In (
 '^""%__AppDir__%wbem\WMIC.exe" UserAccount Where "SID='%%G'" Assoc:List^
 /ResultRole:Name 2^>NUL^"')Do @If Not Defined Usrs (Set Usrs="%%H"
    )Else Call Set "Usrs=%%Usrs%% "%%H""
@Set Usrs 2>NUL|"%__AppDir__%findstr.exe"/LI "\"%~1\"">NUL&&(Exit/B 2)||(
    If Not Defined Usrs (Exit/B 1) Else Exit/B 0)
```

The existing line `10` is included just for demonstration purposes, you would replace that line only with the rest of your script. *i.e. The code to actually create your new user account, and any subsequent verification processes.*

You must not modify anything else except for the following recommendation. Between lines `4` and `5`, perform some validation of the input argument, before continuing with the script. This would be a much better approach that trying to simply capture an error after trying to create your user account.

For example, here are some common Windows username requisites:

- The provided username must consist of at least one character but no more than twenty characters.
- The provided username must not consist exclusively of periods or whitespace.
- The provided username cannot contain any of the following characters: `*/\[]: ;I=,+?<>"@`
  .